# How to get Path Variables in Spring Filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a security filter that needs to do some checks based on the value of the path variable. 
I was trying to do smth like this:

`final Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);`

But the map is always empty, it looks like my filter has higher precedence than the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` that is populating `URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE` attribute in request.

I have tried adding following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandler = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandler.setOrder(0);
        return requestMappingHandler;
    }
}
```

It doesn't help, filters are executed prior to `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` gets called.

relative path example:
`/user/{uid}/action`

I have several paths in my controller. All of them have `uid` path var in the path, but some paths have them set not in the same order, some paths have more than 1 variable.

In my security filter I fetch Auth header, decrypt it, fetch `userId` from it and compare it with path var value. If those ids do not match I return 403.

I am wondering if it is possible to override the order of those 2 actions.
Or, maybe, there is some other way of inspecting path variables in filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring, Filters are executed before Servlets. And `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is called by `DispatcherServlet`, so `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` cannot be used to retrieve path vars in the Filter.
So, I am thinking to either have an Interceptor implemented or go with AOP approach.

Comment: Hey, any solution on this after 2 years :)

Comment: I am waiting as well.