# How to get Path variable in spring filter or java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to get `{testId : 111}` from `/v1/testId/111` example URL.

I know that it is very simple to get path variable if using the `request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)` method.

But, filters are executed before Servlets.

Therefore, `request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)` method is not available.
(ref. [How to get Path Variables in Spring Filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357596/how-to-get-path-variables-in-spring-filter))

---

**Is there any way to retrieve Path Variable within the filter?**

**Or, Is there any way to retrieve Path Variable without `request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)` method?**

The String of `/v1/testId/111` is actually available and I intend to extract 111 from it.

Comment: Do you have `/v1/testId/111` as a String?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad    Yes, `/v1/testId/111` can be obtained using the `request.requestURI` method.

Comment: So why don't you split the uri yourself?

Comment: In the case of the above example, it would be easy to obtain, But it would be difficult if it became more complicated.
For example, for `/v1/testId/111/userId/222`, how do we obtain `{testId:111, userId:222}`?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [lastIndexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_lastindexof.asp), a method of `String`.

```
String foo = "/v1/testId/111";
String theValue = foo.substring(foo.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

`lastIndexOf` returns the numerical position of the last slash in this case and getting the `substring` from the next numerical position will effectively return everything you have after the last slash.

EDIT

If you have more instances, like `/v1/testId/111/userId/222`, then you could `split` your `String`, like

```
String string = "/v1/testId/111/userId/222";
String[] parts = string.split("/");
for (int index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
    if (isNumeric(parts(index))) {
        //Do something with these values as you please
        String entityName = parts[index - 1];
        String entityValue = parts[index];
    }
}
```

`isNumeric` is implemented as such:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    if ((strNum == null) || (strNum.equals(""))) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(strNum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Courtesy to https://www.baeldung.com/java-check-string-number

Comment: what if pathVariable is of data type String?

Comment: @MuddassirRahman it is a String. We split that String and parse the result.